# Global Shortcut To Open Safari

Tags: macos, keyboard, safari, shortcut

Is there a way to set a global shortcut Key to Open Safari in Mac OS?

Comment: I’m assuming you’re aware of spotlight? That’s how I normally open apps. CMD + Space. Can also check out Alfred.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I use Alfred but was trying to get it down to a single keystroke. I found this video on YouTube which gave a easy to implement solution. https://youtu.be/oR8FsCQQH9Y

Comment: If you never quit it, you can always use Command Tab to get to it.

Answer (score 1):

After doing a bit more research I found this video on Youtube which provides a simple easy to implement solution. https://youtu.be/oR8FsCQQH9Y

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.,... I was trying to be brief but understand your point....

Comment: @Qwikatb - not too late to edit & update the answer!